# Why JMeter running thread 6 times when property value says 1

Tags: jmeter

I have ${__P(NUM_USERS, 1)}, ${__P(RAMP_TIME, 1)}, ${__P(NUM_ITERATIONS, 1)} values set.

I have this in the script:
Thread Group
   HTTP Cache Manager
   HTTP Cookie Manager
   CSV User Data Set Config
   Login Controller
      Login Request
      API call - Got JSON Response
      Beanshell - get some stuff out of response and create a hashmap
   Beanshell - Print key and values of HashMap

I am expecting it to run once and exit but it shows the print statement from the beanshell 6 times.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: possibly your bean shell code has a loop which is printing all the key - value pairs in the hashmap.

Comment: The view result tree shows one thread run and beanshell is just doing a for loop to print the content of hashmap. Even if I comment the for loop and add just a System.out statement, it prints 6 times.